# Responsive design, Css, inputs & other items not scaling vertically?

Tags: css, html, flexbox, responsive, css-grid

I am farely new to both HTML & CSS (maybe 4/5 months experience.),
I have started developing several websites as a learning basis, 
& then I realised 
that all of my designs were not 'responsive', so subsequently, I have started to replace all my 'px' values with vw, vh, vmax & vmin.. I have run into some sort of brick wall with my learning curve and wondering if anyone else has experienced this or knows any good sources that could help enlighten me..

Using the 'vw' property is at first sight going well, when I change the browser size everything shrinks, as intended to the viewport width, but getting the vertical scaling of objects, divs, inputs & options is proving to be somewhat difficult. I have attempted playing around with calc() vmin, vmax, vh etc, but they don't seem to be interchangeable unless I stick all of these into css variables. I know that flex-box and grid are designed to be responsive but these still don't seem to do much for the vertical scaling on smaller devices.

I have heard of em's & rems as unit's for font but these are not "responsive",
in the same way Vw & Vh are. ie, changing size on window resize.

Is there something I'm missing, Youtube searches for responsive design only yield hundreds of results for both flex-box and grid. But nothing much for general scaling down of both height and width (proportionatly)..

the first main question is which one is better out of the two
for proportionate scaling 
      (Vmin or Vmax)? across a range of devices?
if I am currently not intending to use any media queries?

I've tried multiple variations of calc(vw -*/+ vmin/vmax) + px/em/vh/vw/rem..
but the vertical measurements still stay the same... Can Anyone point me towards a good resource or video on youtube for this subject..

I'm finding the inspect element/test by device app in firefox very usefull, but need a shove in the right direction.... 
Any Ideas??

Comment: You're question is too broad and might be flagged as such. Have a try at googleing "Learn Responsive", you might even find tons of video on youtube about that !

Comment: I did, but there all to do with flexbox and grid... I will reserch more..

Comment: Should I specify this more towards verticle scaling??

Comment: Do you have an example of something you're trying to scale vertically?

Comment: No, I could add it to Jsfiddle or Codepen, but the main thing that is being a pain is <input> fields and Options for scaling to mobile....

Comment: Sorry, You can close this question, Vmax is the setting i was looking for, without needing to Use Calc() or any other media queries..

Comment: Why has this been down-voted 3 times it is a viable question: both Flexbox & Grid do not address the issue of resizing input fields with there text & placeholder values. It is not too broad, it is clearly asking for the right syntax specifically for inputs that scale them down (evenly) both vertically & horizontally on window resize so that you don't have to mess around with multiple media queries. it is a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing would be to check if you have set the **viewport** meta in your index.html file. If not that should be your very first step. 
Secondly before writing the css for a website, you should go through the flex box and grids in css. You could spare with grids but flex box is of utmost importance. Then you could go further and study a little about the **BEM** model for css. Playing around with percentages and REM’s or vh may not help as you would have a web page which would shrink and expand according to the content that you tend to render. You should therefore make not of the layout of your website and what all things need to stay fixed and what all is going to change when you switch to another device. You should also go through using min-height , max-height and min-width, max-width with flex box that should make your life easy. Good Luck!!!!

Comment: Thank you, I have set the viewport in the metatags, I had never heard of 'BEM model' before, but it is something i will research now. I had played aroud with min/max height/width, but they (except for he width) were not generally being responsive to the content or the height of individual item.. Flex-box and grid defifinately seem to be an invaluable skill/Resource or technology to learn... Thank you for your reply I will. Kind regards. Ryan

Answer (score -2):

try to search about bootstrap because when it comes responsiveness of the website bootstrap is your friend.

Comment: I'm a bit dubious about using librarys. I know it would make my life alot easier but am trying to keep them as a last resort. So I can learn all the in's and out's of Html, Css, & javascript... B4 I then start using Librarys..

Comment: This should be in the comment rather than in the answer. please check here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Bootstrap is one of the best `css` framework but it is not the only way for `Responsive`.

Comment: bootstrap is not my friend. lol, it is djanky and verbose... I preffer having full control of the code, not just partial...